# 401 Unauthorized Access from api request after deploying app to heroku. node. express. axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, axios

My landing page works, but when you go to the home page my app makes a GET request to an API (https://ridb.recreation.gov/docs#/ for info). The pages then stalls. The heroku logs show that the API rejected my request with a 401 unauthorized access. I have my env. variables set up in heroku and the app was working fine locally.

here is some of the response from the api:

```
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041374+00:00 app[web.1]:   response: {
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041375+00:00 app[web.1]:     status: 401,
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041375+00:00 app[web.1]:     statusText: 'Unauthorized',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041376+00:00 app[web.1]:     headers: {
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041376+00:00 app[web.1]:       'content-type': 'application/json',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041376+00:00 app[web.1]:       'content-length': '33',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041377+00:00 app[web.1]:       connection: 'close',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041377+00:00 app[web.1]:       server: 'Server',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041378+00:00 app[web.1]:       date: 'Sat, 14 Nov 2020 00:13:10 GMT',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041378+00:00 app[web.1]:       'x-amz-apigw-id': 'V-IbcGM5oAMF7jw=',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041378+00:00 app[web.1]:       'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; always',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041379+00:00 app[web.1]:       'cache-control': 'max_age=600,public,stale-if-error=3600',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041384+00:00 app[web.1]:       'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041385+00:00 app[web.1]:       'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
2020-11-14T00:13:10.041385+00:00 app[web.1]:       'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
```

and here is my axios code:

[image: my axios api request code]

I tried adding some 'access-control-allow-origin' options but didn't work.

Comment: you seem to be adding the response headers `Access-Control-Allow-*` into the **request** headers - don't do this

Comment: I forgot to thank you earlier for your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who looked at my question. After skimming through the logs I found out Heroku added another set of quotes (' ') on my .env variable that caused the error.